# Multiple versioning URL not working in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0rc

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Multiple versioning was working with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.0.1 but not working in 5.0.0rc.
Now only `api-limited-docs` working URL . Other url not generating.

1. ../api/api-docs  ---not working
2. ../api/api-limitted-docs  ---working

**Following old code.**

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.RoutePrefix = "api-docs";
    string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/swagger.json", "v1");
});
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.RoutePrefix = "api-limited-docs";
    string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/limitted/swagger.json", "v1");
});
```

Comment: Having same issue, trying to find a work around by writing some middle-ware but no luck so far. Any luck on your end?

Comment: @DanielRubio  not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for the latest version it is available.
Here is the change.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.EnableAnnotations();
            c.SwaggerDoc("api", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API - Title", Version = AppClientVersion.LatestVersion});
            c.SwaggerDoc("limited", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "limited- Title", Version = AppClientVersion.LatestVersion});
        });
```